# Socket.io : How to perform certain action while reconnecting after disconnection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, animation, socket.io

I am using node.js and socket.io for building a game .

I have the code as below . The game is simple . It starts doing some animation as soon as it connects to the server and it keeps animating.

I want to make sure that the game fails gracefully if the internet connection goes down or if the server gets disconnected .And the game gets back once the connection is back up .

The animate function fetches content from the server . Hence it will not work properly if there is no connection . I want the animate function to get executed only when there is connection.

So I introduced a variable called connected , which is supposed to hold the status of the connection . if conncted=false , I stop the animation .

But now the problem is socket.io by itself tries to reconnect a few times . How do I set connected to false , during the reconnection process  ?

Game.js

```
var connected = false;

$(document).ready(function(){

//connect to socket server



socket = io.connect('/gameserver');



socket.on('connect', function() {
    connected = true;
    animate();


});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    connected = false;
 socket.connect();

});



});


function animate()

{

....
......
........

if (( connected ) && (..... )) animate();




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following in-built functions to know the status of the connection and accordingly define the status of animation:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){}); // wait for reconnect, hold animation
socket.on('reconnect', function(){}); // connection restored, restart animation  
socket.on('reconnecting', function( nextRetry ){}); //trying to reconnect, hold animation
socket.on('reconnect_failed', function(){ message("Reconnect Failed"); });// end animation
```

nextRetry specifies the time before it will try to connect, if that helps in updating the user with the status.

Moreover on a disconnect from the server, you need not call socket.connect(). The updated status will be available from socket.on('reconnect'). So just include the call to animation here.

It's only if the socket.disconnect has been called from the client, the connection will not be restored automatically and therefore socket.connect() will have to be called again.