# How to know my socket connect is success or not?

Tags: sockets, node.js

I want to do something when the nodejs server is started or I will do something else not related to the server.

But how could I know that. There is no property that shows the status of the connection, and because the socket is asynchronous that I can't get the err by `try..catch...`

The following is my clinet code.

```
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/monitor');
  socket.on('message', function (data) {
                 console.log(data);
             });
```

Anyone can tell me how to `if(is connected).. else..` in this place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try listening to the following events:

```
socket.on( 'connect', function() {

});

socket.on( 'disconnect', function() {

});

socket.on( 'connect_failed', function() {

});

socket.on( 'error', function() {

});
```

Socket.io has some bugs in firing some events so it's better to listen to all of those that might mean a connection failed.

Comment: In addition you could also use the events specified here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094732/socket-io-how-to-perform-certain-action-while-reconnecting-after-disconnection/11096198#11096198